# How to change the parameters of nuxeo

Tags: csv, nuxeo, nuxeo-js-client

I have a problem with Nuxeo, when I want to import my files with their attachements. It's necessary to adopt the parameters of The nuxeo CSV. For example : They define "dc:title" for title and "dc:description" for description.

here is how it works :

```
"name","type","dc:title","dc:description","file:content","dc:creator"
"nuxeo-csv-userdoc","File","Nuxeo CSV User documentation","This is the user guide for Nuxeo CSV","C:/../nuxeo-csv-userdoc.pdf","user"
```

My file is different, and I want to choose my parameters. For example, I have a date, society name, supplier, ID...which is different from what suggest Nuxeo.
Do you have any idea how to do this.

```
"Type","Title","Society","Year","ID","Path","supplier"
"RAPPORT","CENTRIFUGAL PUMPS","EMTECH-E LIST OF PARTS","2005","1767","file.pdf","XY"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must map the import with the custom type that you defined. Have you read https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/how-to-enable-csv-import-on-a-custom-document-type/ ?

> you'll probably want to enable CSV import on the document types you defined, either in Studio or with some code. Here is how to do that.
>   (...)
>   `<require>org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.actions</require>
>   <extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.actions.ActionService"
>     point="filters">
>     <filter id="importFile" append="true">
>       <rule grant="true">
>         <permission>AddChildren</permission>
>         <type>YourCustomTypeID</type>
>       </rule>
>     </filter>
>   </extension>`